# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in SCHED_OTHER

Tags: c

I am running this program but there is an issue which i cannot find.When i put dimensions 50x50x50 the program works fine but when i put for example 50x50x20 i show the error Segmentation fault (core dumped).I dont get it why its doing that.Anyone knows? Here is the code.I am trying to mul array A and B and i use the part to seperate the rows of array A to work equally to threads.Thanks in advance

```
    //SCHED_OTHER
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sched.h>
int part,move=-1;
int **A,**B,**C;
int rows;
int cols;
int cols2;

//AxB arrays
//part used for seperate the work equally for threads
void *mul(){
    int s=++move;
    struct timeval start, end;
    //printf("deadline thread started [%d]\n", gettid());
        struct sched_param params;
        //params.sched_priority =sched_get_priority_min(SCHED_RR);
        sched_setscheduler(0,SCHED_OTHER,&params);
        gettimeofday(&start,NULL);
        for(int k=s*part; k<(s+1)*part; k++){
            for(int j=0; j<cols; j++){
                C[k][j]=0;
                for(int f=0; f<cols2; f++){
                    C[k][j]+=A[k][f]*B[f][j];
                    //sched_yield();
                }
            }
        }
        gettimeofday(&end,NULL);
        printf("Time taken for thread_other %d in microsec %ld\n",s+1,((end.tv_sec*1000000 +end.tv_usec)-(start.tv_sec *1000000 + start.tv_usec)));
        //if rows/5!=0 then the last threads doing the rest rows of array A
        if(s==4 && rows/5!=0){
           for(int k=5*part; k<rows; k++){
            for(int j=0; j<cols; j++){
                C[k][j]=0;
                for(int f=0; f<cols2; f++){
                    C[k][j]+=A[k][f]*B[f][j];
                }
            }
        }
        }
        
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    
    pthread_t t[5];
    srand(time(NULL));
    printf("Give rows of array A\n");
    scanf("%d",&rows);
    printf("Give cols of array A\n");
    scanf("%d",&cols);
    printf("Give cols of array B\n");
    scanf("%d",&cols2); 

    A=malloc(rows*(sizeof(int*)));
    for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){
        A[i]=malloc(cols*(sizeof(int)));
    }
    B=malloc(cols*(sizeof(int*)));
    for(int i=0; i<cols; i++){
        B[i]=malloc(cols2*(sizeof(int)));
    }

    C=malloc(rows*(sizeof(int*)));
    for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){
        C[i]=malloc(cols2*(sizeof(int)));
    }
    for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){
        for(int l=0; l<cols; l++){
            A[i][l]= (rand()%2)+1;
            //A[i][l]=1;
           // printf("%5d",A[i][l]);
        }
        //printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(int i=0; i<cols; i++){
        for(int l=0; l<cols2; l++){
            B[i][l]= (rand()%2)+1;
            //B[i][l]=1;
            //printf("%5d",B[i][l]);
        }
        //printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    part=rows/5;

    
        int res;
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        res=pthread_create(&t[i],NULL,mul,NULL);
        }
    

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        res=pthread_join(t[i],NULL);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){
        for(int l=0; l<cols2; l++){
            printf("%8d",C[i][l]);

        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    free(A);
    free(B);
    free(C);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Fyi, I'd start by crafting a function that is `pthread_create` compliant. `void *mul()` is *not*; `void* mull(void* pv)` would be. Fixing that, debug your code. I think youi'll find you're breaching `C` in your proc.

Comment: what do you mean by that?can you give an example?

Comment: I just did. `void *fn()` is not a valid pthread thread function form. `void *fn(void*)` is. The function sent to `pthread_create` should be one accepting exactly *one* `void*` argument and returning `void*`. Btw, you have a data-race on `move` as well.

Comment: yeah but its run.if i input 50x50x50 dimensions run perfectly and the result of Array C is correct?whats going on when i change dimension.I dont why function is the problem.Thanks in advance. and also for the data-race ,yes move is global variable but if you see into the function i use  the variable S which is not global

Comment: You run this through valgrind or an address sanitizer with the 50x50,20 size and I'll guarantee you you're breaching `C`. (hint: I *know* it breaches because that's exactly how i discovered it; add `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined` to your compile flags if you're using gcc or clang and run it again). And regarding `move`, what do you think `++move` does to that global; and what do you think two threads doing that *concurrently* do ? That's a data race. One you wouldn't need to risk if you used your `void*` to convey per-thread data.

Comment: oh i see.So if a put as an argument to the pthread_create the variable s would solved the problem?

Comment: No, it won't solve the problem. Your function is still broken. Do what I said; run it in a debugger and/or an address sanitizer with the sizing that crashes your program and you'll see.

Comment: Please show the line where you get that error.

Comment: i aam rookie to that .I am trying to understand what i have to do but i dont get it about sanitizer etc etc

Comment: Against, the segmentation fault error message should tell you where it happened. Also you could use a debugger to find it out.

Comment: I get an error and my pc restart when i am trying to debug the program...